How to shuffle cards in javascript?
let cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
shuffle(cards);
console.log(cards);

function shuffle(array) {
    let currentindex = array.length;
    while (currentindex != 0) {
        let randomcards = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
        currentindex -= 1;

        let temp = array[currentindex];
        array[currentindex] = array[randomcards];
        array[randomcards] = temp
    }
    return array
}

My teacher taught me how to shuffle cards , I can understand it all apart from
    let temp = array[currentindex];
    array[currentindex] = array[randomcards];
    array[randomcards] = temp
}
return array

I can't understand why did he write this , can someone explain me how this code act pls ?
I've tried to google but can't find any resource explain clearly about it.

it's swapping 2 elements of the array and is using a temporary variable temp to facilitate the swap

All this does is swap the array items at index currentindex and randomcards.
let temp = array[currentindex]; // create a temp variable to store the value while it's being swapped
array[currentindex] = array[randomcards]; // replace the first item with the 2nd item
array[randomcards] = temp // replace the 2nd item with the 1st item from the temp variable

A simpler way to do this is with destructuring:
[array[currentindex], array[randomcards]] = [array[randomcards], array[currentindex]]; // this is equivalent to the 3 lines above


Imagine you have two cups: the first one contains water and the second one contains wine. You need to swap the drinks. Let's call the first one A and the second one B. Currently, A has water and B has wine. If we want to swap the drinks, we need a third cup (C).
const temp = array[currentIndex]; // A => C
array[currentIndex] = array[randomCards] // B => A
array[randomCards] = temp; // C => A

With this approach we swapped drinks. since your code is written in js you could use array descructuring:
[array[currentindex], array[randomcards]] = [array[randomcards], array[currentindex]]; 

